# Why is it that psychoactive drugs tend to be dangerous?

Tags: medications, side-effects, recreational-drugs, safety

I'm personally not a big fan of recreational drugs, illicit or otherwise, but there's an interesting medical question buried in their use.

Why is it that substances that make you feel good tend to be dangerous? The most effective "feel good" drugs — opioids, benzodiazepines, amphetamines, cocaine in all its forms, MDMA, and of course, alcohol — tend to be very dangerous from a medical perspective, with fairly low therapeutic indices and numerous means of causing harm.

Sources:

- Psychoactive drugs with low [therapeutic index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therapeutic_index): alcohol, cocaine, [opioids](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21999760) (heroin, morphine, codeine, methadone), [amphetamine](https://toxnet.nlm.nih.gov/cgi-bin/sis/search/a?dbs%20hsdb:@term%20@DOCNO%203287) and [barbiturates](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9255991)
- [Margine of exposure of psychoactive drugs](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep08126)
- [Safety ratio of psychoactive drugs](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/8565872_Comparison_of_acute_lethal_toxicity_of_commonly_abused_psychoactive_substances) (click: download pdf)
- [Physical and Psychological Effects of Substance Use](https://ncsacw.samhsa.gov/files/TrainingPackage/MOD2/PhysicalandPsychEffectsSubstanceUse.pdf)

Comment: You mentioned opioids and benzodiazepines as very dangerous from a medical perspective, yet they are prescribed for medical problems.  Can you please provide some articles to back the claim that "the most effective 'feel good' drugs tend to be very dangerous from a medical perspective"?

Comment: The evidence is in their therapeutic indices, which indicate ratio between lethal dose and effective dose. The lower the index, the closer those two doses are, and the easier to overdose. The therapeutic index for acetaminophen is tiny with a few times the recommended dose associated with liver failure, while that of Vitamin B12 is in the millions or higher, making it very difficult to overdose

Comment: Do you have a list of drugs with their therapeutic indices? I think you need to support your assertion that psychoactive drugs have lower TIs.

Comment: Related: [How many people die due to various substance (illegal ones/legal/dangerous ones) per user?](//medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/20037) This is much too broad, and based on a false assumption based on moral panics. It's not that easy to lethally overdose on hemp, champignons, but very easy to overdose on bread if claviceps toxin or Trisetum are in it. Do you want to refine this Q or an answer that seriously 'frame challenges'?

Comment: @LangLangC `"Do you want to refine this Q or an answer that seriously 'frame challenges'?"` -- I don't understand your question. Could you clarify?

Comment: @CareyGregory OP presents a leading question that is unclear and broad. 'Most psychoactives' are *not* 'dangerous' (number of dead for LSD?)… – The Q is framed in a way that taken at face value doesn't result in reasonable As. The scope needs reduction, 'dangerous' & 'psychoactives' definition, etc. In its present form I'd challenge a lot of basic assumptions informing this Q.

Comment: @LangLangC, the OP says that psychoactive drugs "tend to be very dangerous from a medical perspective." We can debate what is a medical perspective, but it certainly is not only "death" and not only "physical damage." Addiction and every other behavior that ruins a person's life is dangerous. Alcohol, opiates, cocaine, LSD, benzodiazepines and even prescribed non-opioid painkillers, like ibuprofen, can be addictive, which by itself is dangerous. I believe it's a legit question that can have a reasonable answer.

Comment: TheEnvironmentalist, would you consider to exclude the last paragraph from the question, because it shifts the focus on the drug market instead on medical problems?

Comment: @Jan When you say "LSD can be addictive" then your definition of "addictive" is either very broken or you are a captive in a maelstrom of moral panic. Know a single case of non-tabloid case of LSD addiction? The "tend" in OPs version is the 'leading' thing. They only *can*, and a proper A may as well explain how they *can*, and how much. Following "tend" isn't medical but political. Very puritanical panicky…

Comment: @LangLangC, the OP uses "tend" because he believes that this is the fact and he says "from medical perspective." What he is saying is a part of question or a hypothesis if you want, so it is the answer that can provide evidence that speaks for or against that claim. I don't see the reason why to pretend and strongly suggest in comments that illicit drugs are not dangerous. Everyone can answer and support his claims with some _evidence._ I've checked few more sources and LSD is actually not considered physically addictive, so I'm not arguing about this one.

Comment: @Jan Following the lead of "tend" & run with ("and this is why") imo is not the proper way to tackle this. Step 1 should be "Do they?" You answer parts of "What are any possible dangers?" (Which is broad, but so basic, as to be findable too easily) We also need risk: measurement, perception, comparison. Clean entheogens and soft inebriants are *much* safer than *many* ordinary OTC drugs like painkillers. Psychedelics vs paracetamol? Hemp vs fentanyl, coca leaves chewed vs coke vs crack? It starts with grouping those all together…

Comment: I'm still waiting for OP to support his assertion that "feel good" drugs have a low therapeutic index. The question states "tend to be very dangerous from a **medical perspective**". That phrase excludes social and legal dangers, as is proper since those dangers are created by people, not the substances. So to establish the very premise of the question evidence is needed that these drugs are, in fact, medically dangerous, and I don't see that evidence. It's just a claim.

Comment: @CareyGregory, I have found some sources that claim that _some_ psychoactive drugs have a low therapeutic index (still searching for actual values) and data for "margin of exposure" for several psychoactive drugs (in my answer).

Comment: @Jan It would be better if those sources were in the question since that's the entire premise of the question.

Comment: @CareyGregory, I understand the claims in the question as a hypothesis, so as questions really. He asks why the drugs are dangerous, he answers with a hypothesis and asks to prove or disprove it.

Comment: @Jan It's not a hypothesis; it's an assertion of fact with no supporting reference. The question lacks prior research and you doing it for him in an answer doesn't change that. If you want to edit the question and add that information that's fine. That's how it should be handled. Answering non-compliant questions puts mods in the position of choosing between closing good answers or being inconsistent about enforcing the guidelines. The next person whose question gets closed for lack of prior research can point to this question as proof there is no such requirement.

Comment: I added some sources into the question.

Comment: @Jan Thanks but they're just general information and don't support the assertion in question.

Comment: No, it is not just general information and it does support the assertion about low therapeutic indices. It's an estimation of margin of exposure and safety ratios for several psychoactive drugs that are in agreement with known estimations of "low therapeutic indices" from other sources. You can't expect to find "official" and "numerical" therapeutic indices for non-therapeutic drugs, so other indices with the same meaning (toxic/safe dose) have been developed.

Answer (score 1):

**Question: Why is it that psychoactive ("feel good") drugs tend to be dangerous?**

The question implies that psychoactive drugs are 1) dangerous and that 2) the reason is in their low therapeutic indices.

**Answer: Psychoactive drugs make one feel good, which, for some people, is addictive, so they start to overuse them. Overuse can result in increased tolerance and this in further overuse and overdose, which is the main reason why these drugs *tend* to be dangerous.**

### DANGERS

**ACUTE DANGERS**

Overdose can result in **acute sickness,** for example, [gastric ischemia with cocaine overdose](https://medcraveonline.com/IJRRT/IJRRT-05-00125.php), or **death,** mainly due to [opioids](https://www.drugabuse.gov/drugs-abuse/opioids/opioid-overdose-crisis) (130/day in US), but also [alcohol](https://www.cdc.gov/vitalsigns/alcohol-poisoning-deaths/index.html) (6/day in US).

Street drugs can be **[adulterated](https://www.thesoberworld.com/2017/07/01/deadly-adulterants-new-dangers-of-illicit-drugs/)** with other dangerous drugs: heroin can be laced with fentanyl, which can cause fatal respiratory depression; ecstasy with "bath salts, which can dangerously increase blood pressure

**Emergency room visits** due to psychoactive drugs use in the US in 2011 ([ussc.gov](https://www.ussc.gov/sites/default/files/pdf/amendment-process/public-comment/20170807/FPD.pdf)):

*V = ER visits/year ; RR = risk ratio (total users/ER visits)*

```
 -                          V       RR
 - PCP (phencyclidine)   75,538     2.9
 - Heroin               258,224     0.92
 - Oxycodone/oxycontin  151,218     0.39
 - Cocaine              505,224     0.37
 - Methamphetamine      102,961     0.23
 - MDMA (Ecstasy)        22,498     0.04
 - Marijuana            445,668     0.03
 - LSD                    4,819     0.03
```

**Road accidents**

In one [2004 study in Netherlands](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15094417), the risk of road trauma was strongly associated with a single use of benzodiazepines (5.1), alcohol (5.5), combination of drugs (6.1) and combination of drugs and alcohol (112.2). *The values in brackets are adjusted odd ratios.*

**CHRONIC DANGERS**

Examples of **chronic physical damage** due to psychoactive drugs, usually after years of overuse:

- [Tobacco smoking](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK232548/): chronic bronchitis, arteriosclerosis (ischemic heart disease, peripheral vascular diseases), throat and lung cancer
- [Alcohol](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/19f0/e6697c57bfa027435ba129c607a8c5507d5d.pdf): liver cirrhosis, alcoholic neuropathy, Wernicke-Korsakoff syndrome, fetal alcohol syndrome
- [Cocaine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3943678/): brain damage
- [Methamphetamine](https://www.drugabuse.gov/publications/research-reports/methamphetamine/what-are-long-term-effects-methamphetamine-misuse): brain damage, tooth decay (meth mouth)

**Withdrawal**

Abrupt withdrawal after prolonged use of certain drugs can be deadly:

- [Alcohol withdrawal](https://www.drugfoundation.org.nz/matters-of-substance/november-2011/mythbusters-death-by-withdrawal/) can be deadly due to seizures or arrhythmia.
- [Opiate withdrawal](https://ndarc.med.unsw.edu.au/blog/yes-people-can-die-opiate-withdrawal) can also be deadly.

Withdrawal symptoms can be expected after prolonged use of drugs that cause [physical dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_dependence): alcohol, nicotine, [caffeine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3131789), opioids, benzodiazepines, GHB and hypnotics (barbiturates, zopiclone, zolpidem).

---

### THERAPEUTIC INDEX

Psychoactive drug overdose is dangerous only if a drug has a low enough therapeutic index.

[Therapeutic index](https://toxtutor.nlm.nih.gov/02-005.html) is the ratio between the dose that is **T**oxic for 50% of population and the dose that is **E**ffective (therapeutic or "feel good") for 50% of population, so a TI = TD50/ED50.

Examples of psychoactive drugs with low therapeutic indices: [alcohol](https://web.cgu.edu/faculty/gabler/drug_toxicity.htm), [amphetamines](https://www.mdedge.com/clinicianreviews/article/72259/addiction-medicine/teen-prescription-drug-abuse-national-epidemic/page/0/2), [barbiturates](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9255991), [some benzodiazepines](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5896864/), [cocaine](https://books.google.com/books?id=utVOHYuhxioC&pg=PA246&lpg=PA246&dq=%22low%20therapeutic%20index%22%20cocaine&source=bl&ots=woQnRCtF5b&sig=ACfU3U28E1U-mvPfFx1gMh1q32yMdc-SzQ&hl=sl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-5aXo--bkAhUNElAKHXrKCJUQ6AEwDnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22low%20therapeutic%20index%22%20cocaine&f=false), [some opioids](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21999760) (especially [heroin](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK441876/)), and [phenylpropanolamine](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/article-abstract/394687).

When psychoactive drugs are not used for therapy, we can't speak about therapeutic indices, so comparable indices, such as "margin of exposure" and "safety ratio" have been developed for these cases.

[Margin of exposure (MOE)](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep08126) is the ratio between the lowest dose found to harm health and estimated drug intake in humans.

[image]

Picture: Margin of exposure for daily drug use estimated using probabilistic analysis; red bar = average user ; error bar = standard deviation ; gray bar = tolerant user *(Image source: [Scientific Reports, Nature.com](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep08126), Open Access)*

Image explanation:

> For individual exposure the four substances alcohol, nicotine, cocaine
>   and heroin fall into the “high risk” category with MOE < 10, the rest
>   of the compounds except THC fall into the “risk” category with MOE <
>   100.

[Another source: RS Gable, Addiction, 2004](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1360-0443.2004.00744.x?sid=nlm%3Apubmed) ([pdf](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/8565872_Comparison_of_acute_lethal_toxicity_of_commonly_abused_psychoactive_substances)) mentions **"safety ratio"** that "was computed for each substance for reported acute lethal dose with the dose most commonly used for non-medical purposes."

```
- Heroin: 6
- Gamma hydroxybutyrate (GHB): 8
- Isobutyl nitrite: 8
- Methamphetamine: 10
- Alcohol: 10
- Cocaine: 15
- MDMA (ecstasy): 16
- Codeine: 20
- Methadone: 20
- Mescaline (peyote cactus): 24
- Flunitrazepam (a benzodiazepin): 30
- Ketamine: 38
- Dimethyltryptamine: 50
- Fluoxetine (Prozac): 100
- Nitrous oxide: >150
- LSD: 1,000 
- Psilocybin (mushrooms): 1,000
- Marijuana: >1,000
```

**In conclusion,** psychoactive drugs can become dangerous when they are overused or overdosed. The danger of a drug can be sometimes explained by its low "margin of exposure" or "safety ratio," but long-term dependence on a drug can be harmful on its own.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. You're simply restating the adverse effects of known drugs. The question asks why can't there be a psychoactive drug with no adverse effects.

Comment: No, the question does not ask that. It's clear as it is: "Why psychoactive drugs tend to be dangerous?" So, this is what I answered: They are dangerous because of circumstances (overdose, overuse, withdrawal, addiction) and not necessary because they are inherently dangerous. To answer _your_ question: There _are_ psychoactive drugs without adverse effects, for example, alcohol in a certain dose.

Comment: The circumstances include prohibition, quality control, miseductaion, disinformation, political abuse and political crimes, like prohibition, other crimes *within* legislation like 3-strike-rule. And that is what you misunderstand: "tend to be" 'assumes medically inherent qualities' 911-call "I'm dying; ate cookie" is no sign of danger, even if an ERvisit follows, not even if a court orders PT. The main dangers are purely from conservative criminals that poured their insanity into law. Unless this is clearly separately analysed and compared in perspective, answer is incomplete.

Comment: We have to shed light on the 'morals' side, as that is one *major root cause* of many of the 'dangers' you list. Intentional overdose is one thing, but popping a pill with unknown ingredients & strength, just because it's illegal? How much violence is 'associated' with hemp, kath, coca-leaves chewing, mushrooms, GHB or poppers? Correctly dosed clean MDMA is by far not dangerous on its own enough to outlaw it. The dangers of dancing or driving or working as roofer or overdosing water? How much alc 'danger' on car-less islands? Death in Thailand ('justice') is worse than any substance.

Comment: @LangLang: To clear the confusion: I do not make an emphasis on "illicit" but on "feel good" drugs, so I included alcohol, benzodiazepines, opioids and I could include the entire group of painkillers, most of which are perfectly legal. A lot of things that makes you "feel good," including certain foods, can become "dangerous" if you overuse them. Eating too much chocolate can easily make you overweight. I don't see _inherent_ dangers in chocolate, but I do see dangers in obesity. I totally don't see anything moralistic in discussing obvious physical and other harms of overuse.

Answer (score 1):

> the illicit drug supply chain has an incentive to make drugs addictive but safe, as a dead client is a bad client

Theoretically yes, however, safety is a cost factor. Everything from packaging to quality assurance has a price tag on it. It would make the drug trade unprofitable. Illegal trade comes with the benefit of being unregulated as well.

Some of these drugs may actually not be safe for everyone to use. Being in a profitable unregulated business, you would not want to lose valuable customers.

Then there is the problem that the substances themselves do not require improving. The therapeutic indices of practically all recreational drugs are nothing out of the ordinary. They are safe enough for medical purposes as long as they are produced and used in a correct and supervised manner in which they even can be used to [treat the addiction](https://drleeds.com/diamorphine/) to them.

Their safety value drops exponentially when put into a recreational setting. You can compare that with motor vehicles. Not unlike drugs, their safety is significantly lower when used recreationally.

That said, lack of safety is not a particular characteristic of [psychoactive substances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoactive_drug). Notable examples are caffeine (coffee, tea) and theobromine (chocolate) and even some [opioids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therapeutic_index).

Comment: I'd like to point out that an overdose is not equivalent to "effective dose". For instance, diamorphine has an LD50 of ~21mg/kg IV while a typical dose is at 5-10mg every four hours. I would strongly suggest to put this whole discussion into a medical context. References derived from law enforcement agencies distort the picture as they lack the above-mentioned medical perspective. As "danger" is always relative, studies comparing psychoactive drugs with other psychoactive drugs isn't helpful to assess their danger (as compared to non-psychoactive drugs) either.

Comment: The concept of let's say *heroin* is also different in a law-enforcement context as it includes everything that the user or the law-enforcement agency *thinks* is heroin, which usually is a cocktail of varying substances of which diamorphine is just the main ingredient.

Comment: "The therapeutic indices of practically all recreational drugs are nothing out of the ordinary." You are saying this without any evidence. Alcohol (ethanol), cocaine, heroin and barbiturates have been all used for medical treatment in the past but no longer (except barbiturates) because of their low therapeutic indices. Most opioids (prescribed or not) have low therapeutic indices and many people die due to their overuse. No drug, when sitting on a shelf, is dangerous, but can become dangerous when someone uses it.

Comment: @Jan Please see the link I provided. It would also be helpful to define "low TI" before turning this into a discussion.

Comment: This topic cannot be discussed just from pure pharmacological viewpoint. Cyanide is also not dangerous when you don't overuse it. It's the "feel good" component that is attractive and commonly leads to overuse, so this explains why these drugs "tend" to be dangerous even if in normal doses are not.

Comment: @Jan The question is not about whether recreational drug is dangerous or not.

Comment: The question in the title is very clear: "Why is it that _psychoactive drugs_ tend to be dangerous?" And it is strictly said: prescribed or not. This is not about "recreational" but about "feel good" drugs as asked in the question. About TI: When it comes to drugs for human use, therapeutic index is usually defined as TD50/ED50, so toxic dose for 50% population/effective (treatment) dose for 50% population. So, not lethal, but toxic dose. To me, a drug has a low therapeutic index when it is _commonly_ overdosed with toxic effects, no matter of the actual TI.

Comment: @Jan No such thing as a therapeutic index in a recreational setting exists. It's lacking the aspect of "therapy". Apart from that, please define "low TI". Give at least an example with a number.

Comment: This is why they use comparable indexes, like "safety ratio" and "margin of exposure," for non-therapeutic drug use. And for prescribed opioids there IS therapeutic index. And still many people die due to overuse of _prescribed_ opioids.

Comment: @Jan I think you mean "abuse" of prescription opioids.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99083/discussion-between-life-on-mars-and-jan).